# How to stream data from a relational database to GCP (bigquery preferrably) through a REST API?

Tags: database, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, data-stream

I have CMS data on a custom-built database I have no access too, I want to basically backfill all data and stream all new data in realtime to bigquery or any gcp storage.

Now I have checked out datastream and pubsub but I still can't get the hand of it. The closest I have gotten to what I want was when I tried out the http poller on datafusion.

I also tried airbyte and no proper data was flowing and either way I do not like using 3rd paty connectors as I dont trust them to be honest.

What can I do to stream ini realtime all record on a database (sort of a replica) to bigquery????

I tried dataflow and datastream and was lost and couldn't really find what I need to do.

I am expecting all data on the database to be copied to gcp through rest api and then have a realtime stream as soon as new records are entered to initial database basically to be mirrored in gcp.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this question.
Datastream can help in moving data to GCS or Bigquery. Also, it can capture any Change data capture.
Datastream can connect only with MySQL, PostgreSQL, AlloyDB and Oracle databases at the moment and can load data into BigQuery, Cloud SQL, Cloud Storage, and Cloud Spanner as per your use case. If you have any of the source database where your data is sitting then only datastream can be a good option.
I hope this helps.